# App engine backend killed every few minutes

Tags: google-app-engine

My app engine backend process is killed with a message "Process moved to a different machine", between 3 to 5 minutes after being started. This happened 10 times in a row. 
Is it possible to have a backend process last more than 3 minutes on app engine?

Comment: Almost anything is possible as long as you're willing to pay for it.

Comment: That would be great. Right now I pay for a process that is killed, so useless :(

Comment: Yes: [here are the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) on modules (for _Backends_ see _manual scaling_).  Similar docs are available for Python, etc.  What is your process doing?

Comment: Well, the docs say that the process can be moved around for load balancing and in case a machine is shut down. They advise to save the state regularly. But seriously, every minute or so, having to write down anything to database? That's extremely annoying.

Comment: I'm using Basic Scaling with Instance Class "B8" and am not seeing my process moved around a lot.  It successfully runs for 24 hours as per the limit.  I did have to upgrade the app but it hasn't cost me a lot (yet).

Comment: I'm using B8 too. You're lucky. The max I get is a few minutes, it's really annoying.